# Wanted to pull current month -2 months

Tags: sql, sas

I wanted to pull `current_month - months` in SAS, I tried through intnx function. But it is not working for me.

```
DATA
 input_file
 ;
 input
  @1 DHQ_ID             5.
  @7 AS_OF_DT           DATE9.
  @22 CUST_THIS_MONTH_SPEND  7.5
  ;
FORMAT    AS_OF_DT       DATE9.
   ;
DATALINES;
10970 01OCT2014 0
10970 01NOV2014 0
10970 01JAN2015 0
10970 01FEB2015 0
10970 01MAR2015 0
10970 01APR2015 20
10970 01MAY2015 800
;
RUN;

%LET date = "01FEB2015"d;

proc sql;
    create table master_zero as select 
        dhq_id, 
        sum(case  when cust_this_month_spend <= 0 OR 
                  (INTNX('month',&date.,-2)) IS NULL
       then 1 else 0 end)as cnt_zero 
    from input_file
        where 
        as_of_dt between intnx('month',&date.,-2) and &date. 
        group by dhq_id 
        order by dhq_id;
quit;


data master_zero2 (drop = cnt_zero);
    set master_zero (where = (cnt_zero = 3));
    format dt date9.;
    dt = &date.;
run;
```

Result:

```
DHQ_ID  CNT_ZERO dt 
10970   2        01DEC2014
```

Comment: DATA
 input_file
 ;
 input
  @1 DHQ_ID          5.
  @7 AS_OF_DT      DATE9.
  @22 CUST_THIS_MONTH_SPEND  7.5
  ;
FORMAT    AS_OF_DT    DATE9.
   ;
DATALINES;
10970 01OCT2014 0
10970 01NOV2014 0
10970 01JAN2015 0
10970 01FEB2015 0
10970 01MAR2015 0
10970 01APR2015 20
10970 01MAY2015 800
;
RUN;


%LET date = "01FEB2015"d;

Comment: So HOW is it not working?  Does your code generate an error? Does it not return the result you wanted?  What result do you want for that input?

Comment: Why do you have that OR condition in your CASE statement? I think that may be an issue: `sum(case  when cust_this_month_spend <= 0 OR 
                  (INTNX('month',&date.,-2)) IS NULL
       then 1 else 0 end)as cnt_zero`

Comment: I am expecting 01Dec2014, because 01Feb2015 -2 month is Dec2014, which is not in my datalines. But i am expecting this value in output

Comment: What would you want if 01JAN2015 was also not present ?  Does &date represent current_month ?

Comment: @Richard  Then again it should print as 01Dec2014 which is current month-2months

Comment: @Reeza then what should be an alternate way

Comment: @vmaha13 no idea because no idea what that line should be doing. I suspect its not doing whatever you think it's doing though.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you show does not read `CUST_THIS_MONTH_SPEND` properly, you might want

```
@17 CUST_THIS_MONTH_SPEND  best7.
```

instead of

```
@22 CUST_THIS_MONTH_SPEND  7.5
```

You can count the number months, for each group, with `0` spending -or- unrecorded spending made within 3 months prior to a target month as follows:

- restrict rows to those within 3 months prior
- sum logic evaluation to count known zeroes
- count non-existent months by subtracting number of existent rows (`count(*)`) from expected rows (`3`)

Example:

```
DATA have;
 format groupid 8. as_of_dt date9.;
 input groupid as_of_dt DATE9. spending; DATALINES;
10970 01OCT2014 0
10970 01NOV2014 0
10970 01JAN2015 0
10970 01FEB2015 0
10970 01MAR2015 0
10970 01APR2015 20
10970 01MAY2015 800
;
RUN;

%LET month = "01FEB2015"d;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    groupid,
    sum(spending = 0) + 3 - count(*) as zeromissingCount,
    &date as ending_month format=monyy7.
  from have
  where intck('month', &date, as_of_dt) between -2 and 0
  group by groupid
  ;
```